# Why an .xls file created with python csv and StringIO could be corrupted or unsafe?

Tags: excel, python-3.x, reactjs, axios, flask-restful

I have a react component that makes an ajax call (with axios) to my little api and then I get the data response in an ".xls" file that is downloaded automatically. All works fine, but when I open the .xls file, Excel warns me with the following message:

> File format and extension of 'myfile.xls' don't match. The file could
>   be corrupted or unsafe. Unless you trust its source, don't open it. Do
>   you want to open it anyway?

If I ignore this warn and I continue opening the file, it is opened and show's me the data that I expected correctly. 
But it is not very elegant to see this message for the user, how can I remove it?

My code is the next:
The code that creates the xml:

```
from io import StringIO  
import csv

MyAPIClass(Resource):
 (...)
    si = StringIO()
    cw = csv.writer(si, dialect='excel-tab')
    cw.writerows(dataset) #my iterable data list# 
    output = make_response(si.getvalue())
    output.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
    output.headers["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=installations.xls"
    return output
```

The code to handle the axios (ajax) call to download the file created by my api:

```
exportToExcel() {
const FileDownload = require('react-file-download');
axios({method:'post', url: '/myapi_to_excel', headers: {'Accept': ' text/csv'})
        .then(res => {
            FileDownload(res.data, 'myfile.xls');
        });
}
```

Thank you!!! Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's because .xls is a very old extension of excel. This extension is for 97-2003. If you change your script to create a .xlsx file afterwards everything should be fine.